# Which Python intrpetor should I be putting in .py header?

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu LAMP server.  The machine would be dedicated to one site, and the site has a few .py files I'm working on.  It would seem I have the PHP and MySQL up and running, but the Apache doesn't seem to be executing the .py files (just downloading them).

I then noticed that there seem to be two Interpreters, one at `/usr/bin/python` and one at `/usr/local/bin/python`

Which one should my headers be pointing to?  At the moment I have `!#usr/local/bin/python`

I note that I also could have a problem with apache2.conf, but I'm not so sure.  Using a virtual host I added a cgi handler (and tried `mod_python`) with no luck.  I could post up the whole vitrual host from apache2.conf of that would help.

I've chkmod +rwx *.py in the site folder.  Perhaps I should split this into to two posts, but I think they might be related.

Thanks

Comment: The second problem about the `apache2.conf` is a definitely a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the environment decide, which should mean it'll execute using whatever executable is run when you run `python` in your shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Code goes here
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  This didn't make the LAMP server work, but it's good to know fix the Python script.